# Animate re build in SliverList when scroll... or i dont use it well

Tags: flutter-animation

i have an animation in sliverlist that is build through by stream builder...
i animation is fine when loaded at start but it's animation again and again when i scroll...
does any one know what can be the problem ?

i have tryied to put a controller to the list and stop it until i have new data in the stream but still it's the same effect

here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: controllerGetx.formatDateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                      'waiting...'))); // Show a loading spinner while waiting for data
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return SliverFillRemaining(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
        }

// here is the list builder
return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            String time = initialSlots[index]['time'];
            List users = initialSlots[index]['users'];           
            Map<String, dynamic>? currentUserMap = users.firstWhere(
              (map) => map['uid'] == controllerGetx.currentUser?.uid,
              orElse: () => <String, dynamic>{},
            );

            bool isUserinCurrentList = currentUserMap!.isNotEmpty;
            String? username =
                isUserinCurrentList ? currentUserMap!['username'] : null;

// here is the animation for the list...

            return Animate(
              effects: [FadeEffect(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 650))],
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  users.isEmpty
                      ? cardEmpty(
                          date: controllerGetx.currentDate.value,
                          time: time,
                          users: users,
                          addUsertoTime: addUsertoTime)
                      // if user in the list then show your list
                      // with your details
                      : isUserinCurrentList
                          ? cardWithyou(
                              time: time,
                              users: users,
                              username: username,
                            )
                          : cardFull(
                              date: controllerGetx.currentDate.value,
                              time: time,
                              users: users,
                              addUsertoTime: addUsertoTime)
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          childCount: initialSlots.length,
        ));
      },
    );
  }
```

i'm tyring to get the list show one time as animation and thats it, not animate again when i scroll

Comment: i was able to overcome this by using auto_animated package...
but the controller that was set up in getx is not attached for some rason to the livesliverlist... i dont know why...